# forkJoin for multiple NgRx Store subscription

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx

I have multiple store subscriptions in an array and I want to use forkJoin to get the result only when all observables return a result.
Something like that:

```
this.subscriptionsArray = this.store.select('state')
forkJoin(this.subscriptionsArray).subscribe(sub => {
  // do something here with response
});
```

The problem is that the store doesn't emit anything.

I found a solution on a GitHub repo:

```
this.subscriptionsArray = this.store.select('state').pipe(first())
```

This work, but I need the last emitted result and the obvious solution doesn't work. The following code doesn't work:

```
this.subscriptionsArray = this.store.select('state').pipe(last())
```

Comment: How about `combineLatest`? It emits when all observables *emit*. `forkJoin` emits when all observables *complete*.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your observable is not fire and forget type, so you can not get the last emitted value, because:

> Emit the last value emitted from source on completion, based on
>   provided expression.

Reference: [last filtering operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/last.html)

You should try [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html):

> When any observable emits a value, emit the latest value from each.

```
combineLatest(...this.subscriptionsArray).subscribe(value => console.log(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [withLatestFrom](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/withLatestFrom) operator, so your code can be like:

```
const sub = this.store.select(selectStore1).pipe(
  first(),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectStore2).pipe(first())),
  concatMap(([selectStore1, selectStore2]) => {
    // do something
  })
)
```